# Why does apache's mod_status extended status slow down the server?

Tags: apache-2.2

The apache docs for mod_status say that turning on extended status can slow down the server. In what way would this happen? Does it use more cpu? Memory? Spawn extra processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Because it uses so many additional hamsters in the little wheels that inevitably, a few end up running in the opposite direction, thereby slowing the whole thing down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from [Apache Performance Tuning Guidlines](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html)

> mod_status and ExtendedStatus On
>   If you include mod_status and you also set ExtendedStatus On when building and running Apache, then on every request Apache will perform two calls to gettimeofday(2) (or times(2) depending on your operating system), and (pre-1.3) several extra calls to time(2). This is all done so that the status report contains timing indications. For highest performance, set ExtendedStatus off (which is the default).

Answer (score 2):

It needs to compile, store and keep track of extra statistics.  I haven't read the code but my gut tells me it uses a bit more memory and considerable more CPU cycles.